# Forward all properties of a control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, properties, controls, forwarding

I'm making a custom control (that's what I do, I'm a theme designer) and I'm having trouble with something.
The control I'm making is a custom RichTextBox control. Since I want a custom border (rounded edges) arround the RichTextBox, I simply have a control with custom borders, and a child control which is actually a normal RichTextBox. With the BorderStyle set to none, it looks like this:

[image: My rich textbox control]

Now, of course, the parentcontrol needs to have all the properties a normal RichTextbox has.
I manually did all the properties for a regular textbox, but a RichTextBox has far more properties and I was asking myself, is there any way to "forward" all properties of the child control to the main control?

Maybe I'm explaining it a bit oddly. Basically, when you change the main control's "Text" property the RichTextBox's Text property should change too. This means I have to write a custom event for every Property a RichTextBox has, isn't there a way to do this for every property automatically?

Thanks in advance,

Mavamaarten.

Comment: No, there is no shortcut to make the container control "inherit" the properties and events and methods of the child rich text control.  You might be able to create a method to generate the code for you using reflection.  When it comes to "themes", the general advice is to look at WPF or 3rd party software.

Comment: Making the themes isn't the problem, I just wondered wether there was a quicker way of "remaking" all the properties. I guess there really is no way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

> *Note: I answered this **before** the posted had the **WinForms** tag in their question. (I actually added it based on his reply here.)  Still, if you're using WPF, this is how you'd do it...*

The easiest thing to do is to replace the ControlTemplate with your internal implementation.  In other words, you're replacing the 'visual' portions of the RichTextBox control but you're still a RichTextBox control.

For instance, this is how I replaced the visuals of a TextBox to completely strip away all the chrome and leave it with nothing more but a simple border.  But it was still a full TextBox with all properties, etc.

Again, look up Control Templating.  You may also want to search for 'Lookless Controls'.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type glc:EditableTextBlock2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">

    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type glc:EditableTextBlock2}">

                <Border Name="Bd"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Border.Background}" >

                    <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />

                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. However, I am working with Windows Forms applications, not WPF.

Comment: You should add that to your tags for the question.

Comment: I already had "Winforms" in the tags, I thought that would be clear ;)

Comment: Actually, no you didn't.  I added it after your reply. Check the edits.  :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm new here, you probably noticed.

Comment: No worries! We were all new at some point!  Since this isn't getting much attention (and if you still need an answer) you may want to consider re-wording your question, or at least the title itself.  People tend to scan through these to see if they want to take a stab at answering them.  If it doesn't say enough, it'll fail the 'scan test' and your question would go unanswered.